# Ethereum private blockchain: peers can not see each others via internet

Tags: ethereum

this is maybe a common question with many answers on internet but i can not make it work, so please help to give some hints

i setup the Ethereum private blockchain with the steps at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network

the first node has been started with basic parameter like :

```
geth --datadir "firstNode" --identity "firstNode" --networkid 65535000 --rpc --nat "any" --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

the second pc in local network has been started with bootNodes of the 1st node enode address

even in the same network, these PC did not see each others with admin.peers cli,
instead, i see other enode of outside internet

when i try to connect my 3rd PC ( my laptop) from internet to my private block chain that is same networkid (say 65535000)

i supposed that i just need one 24/7 running node as bootnode so that other PC can start with that bootnode the the peers will automatically find out themselves as many document said. but in really i can not form up a private chain for testing, i tried many solutions but the issue still there, what i'm mining now is others blocks from internet , not my blocks

is there any option i'm missing ?

```
checked: 
- my internet router open the uPNP by default 
- the two pc need to addPeer(enode address) manually to see each others, without manual peering, they could not find themselves even they are boot up with the bootnodes from geth cli at startup
- from outside, i'm trying to peer with my local private chain by connecting to the 1st node with the public IP (check on router) on enode address, but doesn't help
```

I'm so confusing now and dont know what exactly to look up

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ethereum now has its own stack exchange. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Which tool are you using to build this application?

I personally faced this issue on [IBM Bluemix](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain/) , was not able to discover peers via internet but in bluemix I found this solution

> > On the Blockchain dashboard under the Network tab there will be action buttons on the right side of the panel for each validating peer. If the peer is stopped one of the actions will be start. Select that button. If you are using Hyperfabric then you should consider similar settings.